# Selenium Select Options NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

While attempting to select an option in the following form, my script throws a `NoSuchElementException` when I try to select the option by both `select.selectByVisableText(" 85% - Text 1")` and `select.selectByValue("85")` methods. I know the select element exists on the page, and the css selectors are configured correctly, as I can dump the options with `select.getOptions()`. I can select values via `select.selectByIndex(1)` however.

```
<select id="confidence" name="confidence">
<option value="100">100% - Text 0</option>
<option selected="" value="85"> 85% - Text 1</option>
<option value="75"> 75% - Text 2</option>
<option value="65"> 65% - Text 3</option>
<option value="50"> 50% - Text 4</option>
<option value="7"> 7% - Text 5</option>
<option value="0"> 0% - Text 6</option>
</select>
```

Using Java 1.7, Firefox 31.0, Selenium 2.41.0, and JUnit 4.11 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could select your option with a for-loop the following way:

```
List[] options = select.getOptions();

for (int i = 0; i <= options.length - 1; i++) {
   if (options[i].getValue().equals(" 85% - Text 1") {
      select.selectByIndex(i);
   }
}
```

But if you want to solve the problem clean you should check the following points:

- is your select visible/displayed
- if not, why isn't it (maybe it has to be called by another element)

And a little bit more Information could be useful to help you solve this problem not with a workaroun. (example code)

p.s.: The workaround is not tested by me but it should work... if it doesn't please tell me.

Comment: The script-Coder where your exception occurs could be helpful. Also the initialization of your webdriver. And did you try the workaround? Does it work?